# ArcPy ExtractValuesToPoints from raster with select by attribute

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, feature-layer

I'm trying to extract values from different rasters to a selection of points. So I try to iterate through each raster and for each extract the values and join, append them to a set of points, which are changing for each iteration. I do not understand why it does not work.
I figure I can't call the selection layer to copy it. Do you see any obvious mistakes?

I do not have the error messages but different happened, one being that the selected layer"sel_points_lyr" does not exist. I've tried to make feature layer and all different clumsy variants but I'm lost.

Here's the code:

"alpha" is a field name of the point FC on which I want to select points that match a part of the iterated raster name.

```py
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\home\in_rasters.gdb"
# Workspace, variables
Points = r"C:\home\input_points.gdb\points"
tmp_workspace = r"C:\home\temp.gdb"
joined_fc = r"C:\home\results.gdb\points_all_joined"
sel_points_fc= r"C:\home\input_points.gdb\points_sel"

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

listRa = arcpy.ListRasters("*","")  
for raster in listRa:
    where_clause= "alpha= '" + str(raster[16:24])+ "'"
    sel_points_lyr= arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Points, "NEW_SELECTION", where_clause)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(sel_points_lyr, "sel_points_fc")
    tmp_points= os.path.join(tmp_workspace, 'points_tmp' +raster[16:24])
    ExtractValuesToPoints(sel_points_lyr, raster, tmp_points, None,"VALUE_ONLY")
    arcpy.Append_management(tmp_points, joined_fc, "TEST")
```

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish when you use `raster[16:24]`?

Comment: @Aaron this is the timestamp portion of each raster, such as "20200814" for example, it is comprised in the raster input name, so I extract it from the raster name. I hope to use it for 1) build the SQL query dynamically, one for each raster/iteration 2) to then create one FC of points with the values from the raster being iterated

Comment: Do you want to use only selected point in this line:  ExtractValuesToPoints(sel_points_lyr, raster, tmp_points, None,"VALUE_ONLY")? Because you should use "sel_points_fc" in this case.

Comment: Use AddFieldDelimiters and format (function) to build your where clause. In SelectLayerByAttribute `Points` should be a layer, now it is a feature class.

Comment: Thanks @david_p That helped me make it work

Comment: @BERA thanks, don't unserstand the advantage I use it now